# Cannot re-set form submit button to disabled

Tags: javascript, html, forms, disabled-control, submit-button

On a webpage I have a form:

```
<form action="/SignUp.py" method="post">
    <input required type="text" name="fullName" onKeyPress="checkFinished()" autofocus>
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Sign Up" disabled>
</form>
```

and script:

```
<script>
    function checkFinished() {
        if (document.getElementsByName("fullName")[0].value.match(/. ./).length > 0) {
            document.getElementsByName("submitButton")[0].disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementsByName("submitButton")[0].disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

If I step through the code using Firebug, I can see the execution path is correct. However, when the code hits the else clause and should be (re-)disabling `submitButton`, it does not get disabled. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What pattern are you trying to match with this regexp `/. ./`?

Comment: @dfsq any char, then a space, then any char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a little fiddle for you to take a look at

https://jsfiddle.net/mo5wfjLt/2/

What is wrong in your code :

First of all, backspace is not triggering a `keypress` event, so you will have a problem there in case you want to delete characters. Use `keyup` instead. If you want to experiment with key events, try this out: http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

The next major error is this line

```
document.getElementsByName("fullName")[0].value.match(/. ./).length
```

If a `document.getElementsByName("fullName")[0].value.match(/. ./)` does not exist, this returns `null`, so when you immediately try to access `.length` on that, you are trying to do `null.length`, so you get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Also it's a good practice to keep values such as `document.getElementsByName("fullName")[0]`, for example, in variables. It helps.

So, check the fiddle, and if there is something you still don't understand, ask.

Comment: actually, backspace does generate a ``keyPress`` event.

Comment: @Conrad well, you are right, but it's inconsistent. On Mac, `keypress` does fire an event in Firefox but not in Chrome and Safari

Comment: I am on a Mac too (10.9.5), using Firefox 36.0.1 - not sure what to say. I can set a breakpoint in ``checkFinished`` in Firebug and it stops when I press the 'delete' key.

Comment: @Conrad I heavily modified my comment, sorry, do a page refresh :) (also, above I meant "... backspace does fire an `keypress` in ..." )

Comment: ``keyUp`` is the important event here - I will get the current version of the text in value, as opposed to the other 2 events, which give the prior state of ``value``. However, using ``RegExp.test()`` as mentioned in @Moogs's answer is the cleaner code IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex does the following:

```
/. ./
```

- matches any character (except newline)
- matches the character   literally
- matches any character (except newline)

`match` method returns an array with results otherwise it returns `null`.

When there is no match your program is throwing an error because `null` does not have a `length` property. So the function throws an exception and the rest of the program within your script tag does not run.

One solution is to use `test` method which returns a boolean.

`/. ./.test(document.getElementsByName("fullName")[0].value)`

**JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vbgp6gba/2/**